# aws ec2 iptables port 80 (http)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables, rhel

I recently setup an ec2 Instance (RHEL) on Amazon Web Services. I am having trouble getting it to respond to http requests. I understand that port 80 (http) needs to be added to the inbound rules in the instance's security group. This hasn't worked so far - I've tried both adding it to the default security group, and creating a new security group.

Has anyone else had a similar experience? Next step is Amazon support, but thought I would ask here first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in case anyone else stumbles upon this, I found an answer on AWS support forums:

Hello,

Since you are running a RedHat 6 AMI in your instance, you should check that redhat firewall rules are not blocking access to your services, and if so, reconfigure it.

You can use the following command:

**system-config-firewall-tui**

to reconfigure the firewall.

Comment: disable firewall is safe on AWS? anyone have an idea?